# Using terminal to find PDF size

Tags: terminal, grep

This is a normal output using `pdfinfo`

```
Creator:        Pages
Producer:       Mac OS X 10.10.1 Quartz PDFContext
CreationDate:   Tue Mar  3 01:26:34 2015
ModDate:        Tue Mar  3 01:26:34 2015
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          5
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      242463 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

So I know I can do something like this to grab the amount of pages:

```
pdfinfo document.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'
```

I am trying to get the page size to put something like `612 x 792`.

At the moment I am trying things like `grep "Page size:"` but it's obviously not the right way. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep/sed work:

```
pdfinfo document.pdf | \
    grep "Page size:" | \
    sed -e 's/^[^:]*:[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]pts.*//'
```

using grep to simplify the text to just the line you are interested in, then using sed to chop off the beginning and end of the line (for the example you showed).

In this example, there are two sed options (each is a script).  Both change characters matching a given pattern to nothing, e.g.,

```
s/old/new/
```

but here `new` is an empty string.

The "^" character at the beginning is an "anchor", matching the beginning of the line.  The "[^:]" uses "^" differently, matching any character except ":" (and the "*" says zero-or-more).  So given "Page size:", that matches the whole thing.  After the ":" on your line, there is some whitespace (which may be spaces or tabs).  The POSIX character class "[:space:] matches either, and is put inside brackets as you see: "[[:space:]]".  Finally, the ".*" in the second option matches any character (.) zero or more times (*).

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Anyway you can break down what is happening here? How does it know what to cut off?